# Delete Document with all inheritance sub documents

Tags: javascript, mongodb

I have the following code in MongoDB:

process schema:

```
var process = new Schema({

name: { type: String},

parentProcess:{ type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'process' }


db.process.insertMany([

   { _id : 1, name : "Process 1"},

   { _id : 2, parentProcess : 1, name : "Sub 1" },

   { _id : 3, parentProcess : 1, name : "Sub 2" },

   { _id : 4, parentProcess : 2, name : "Sub 2-1" },

   { _id : 5, parentProcess : 2, name : "Sub 2-2" },

   { _id : 6, parentProcess : 3, name : "Sub 3-1" },

   { _id : 7, parentProcess : 3, name : "Sub 3-2" }
]);
```

My question is:

I want to delete the mail process `id:1` with all child and sub child processes, I tried the middleware `.pre` but I got an error message as follows:

> .pre in not a function

Comment: what's your document level? 2 or infinity?

Comment: infinity levels